# How to find the vertical and horizontal distance from the center of a rectangle

Tags: java, math

For my current Java project I have to compute the horizontal and vertical distance from the center of a rectangle. I tried using the formula from a previous project to find such a distance. Here is my code:

```
    // Calculations; centerCoordinate = 0
    formula = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(userXCoordinate - centerCoordinate, 2) + Math.pow(userYCoordinate - centerCoordinate, 2));
```

My professor gave the hint that a point is in the rectangle if its horizontal distance to (0, 0) is less than or equal to 10 / 2 and its vertical distance to (0, 0) is less than or equal to 5 / 2. I tried using 5 for horizontal distance and 2.5 for vertical distance and setting variables to these numbers. I then made an if-else loop saying if the result of the formula was less than or equal to the variables the coordinates were in the rectangle otherwise they were outside. This returned a wrong answer; what could I do differently?

Comment: Don't describe code. Post it. Tell us what you expect as the result when executing the code, and what you get instead.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out if the point is contained in the rectangle or the distance from the center or both? The distance from one point to the center of the rectangle doesnt directly correlate to intersection like it would with a circle.

Comment: I am trying to find out if the point is contained in the rectangle.

Comment: @N.Ali There are thousands of references on websites about this topic. Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle .

Answer (score 1):

So, let's say first, the coordinate of the center is:
(x=2.5, y=1.25)

See the below for explanation

```
               <-10/2 ->
   (0,0) _____________________
    |                         |  ^
    |                         |  |
    | Center is (5/2, 2.5/2)  | 5/2
    |                         |  |
    |_________________________|  v
```

The point is, you can not use the distance from the center to determine if the point is in the rectangle or not, because it is a rectangle not a circle.
Below is the right way to check if user coordinate is in rectangle or not.

```
if(userXCoordinate < 10/2 && userYCoordinate < 5/2 )
{
  //user Coordinate is in the rectangle
}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation; I will give this a try now!

Comment: Nice ASCII graphics and I give it a +1, but I assumed from the professor's mentioning of "10 / 2" and "5 / 2" that (5, 2.5) was the center -- dividing a rectangle's dimension by 2 is the standard way of getting the center.

Comment: Thanks for that as well, Thomas.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Calculations; centerCoordinate = 0
formula = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(userXCoordinate - centerCoordinate, 2) + Math.pow(userYCoordinate - centerCoordinate, 2), 2);
```

You almost got it. :)

Comment: Doesn't even compile. What is `Math.sqrt(someNumber, 2)` supposed to be?